# Scss change variable based on file loaded

Tags: javascript, sass

In my react app I lazy load 2 theme files for light mode and dark mode. I want to have 1 variable for each color and not 2 variables (ie: `$bgLight: white` and `bgDark: black`). What I have tried doing is lazy loading dark and light mode scss files. If the theme is light mode I want to change my main variable based on the theme so that when I use the variable in code I just use $bgColor and not use any conditionals or adding classes.

I tried using the `@use '' with ()` scss syntax but it doesnt work. In my main variables.css file I set the bgColor as `$bgColor: black !default;`. When the light mode scss file is loaded it doesnt change the bgColor. How can I change it within the light mode scss file

Answer (score -1):

This is not exactly what you want. Nonetheless it solv thee problem.

Use css inline variable.

#### Dark mode

```
<div class="o-grid" style="--bg-color: black">
    <aside></aside>
    <main></main>
</div>
```

#### Light mode

```
<div class="container" style="--bg-color: white">
    <aside></aside>
    <main></main>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    background: var(--bg-color);
}
```

https://ishadeed.com/article/css-variables-inline-styles/

Comment: I need to be using scss as the question says and its hard to maintain inline styles